# gitlab-ci deploying error variable KUBECONFIG

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

Sorry if my question is a bit trivial, but I'm just getting close to understanding how pipelines work in gitlab.

Some time ago I configured my gitlab-ci to deploy on an azure environment. In particular, I ran this command without receiving any errors

```
stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir -p $(dirname $KUBECONFIG)
    - helm repo add repos "https://$TOKEN$REPO"
    - helm repo update
```

The mkdir worked without any problem, but after some updated in kubernetes and gitlab version the variable $KUBECONFIG is not valorized. So the pipeline stop with an error. Could someone explain to me how the KUBECONFIG variable is valued and why it now gives an error?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a lot of information to provide a useful answer. What is the error that you are getting?

In general, according to gitlab docs, $KUBECONFIG is

*"The path to the kubeconfig file with contexts for every shared agent connection. Only available when a GitLab agent is authorized to access the project."*
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

It is possible that your command works, but that it did not create the correct directory.

```
mkdir -p $(dirname $KUBECONFIG)
```

This can succeed as long as it creates a directory, any directory. So there are a few possibilities why mkdir did not fail before. Impossible to tell without pipeline log.

It can also help to add en echo or printenv into the pipeline, so that you can see exactly what is the value of $KUBECONFIG.